# Getting NullPointerException When Setting Listview FirstVisiblePosition

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

When Listview reached the end position(onscroll) i will  get data from database and i need to set position for listview when doing this am Getting NullPointerException

please see the logcat report

```
Listview TagslistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
int index = TagslistView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); 
TagslistView.setSelectionFromTop(index+1,0);
```

Logcat

```
a05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112): Process: com.example.co, PID: 22112
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at com.example.co.CustomList.getView(CustomList.java:58)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1337)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1620)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4641)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4641)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4641)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4641)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4641)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2018)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1775)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-15 14:32:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(22112):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your variable TagsListView is null. Or it's class? In java commonly class names starts with UpperCase and variable with lowercase

Comment: what is tagslistView? looks to me like that isn't instantiated.

Comment: The code provided holds very little value. Where is the stacktrace? NullPointers are rarely hard to fix, read the stacktrace, find the row mentioned, fix it!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TagslistView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```